# How to fix output from tty of Docker for macOS vm?

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

I try to connect vm by command:
`screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty`
and got this:
[image: tty output]

Comment: What command did you start your docker container with? I can't reproduce this.

Comment: @Frap its not a docker container, its host linux vm from Docker for macOS https://github.com/docker/for-mac#component-projects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I add the same issue after running 
`screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty`
 then closing my terminal and running that command again.

To fix try to do in the screen:
`CTRL+A CTRL+\ followed by "y"`

Comment: This is needed because if you just close the terminal window, screen is still connected to that TTY in background (detached)... so you can (in new terminal window) list sessions with `screen -ls` and then re-enter the session with `screen -r`, then properly exit with `ctrl-a, k`

Comment: I added all the commands with notes you need to connect to VM in a gist https://gist.github.com/BretFisher/5e1a0c7bcca4c735e716abf62afad389

Comment: As of Docker 18.03.0-ce-mac59, the path to the tty is `Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty`.

Comment: I don't know when it happened but as far as I can tell there is no longer a way to connect to the Docker VM using screen. I'm running Docker Desktop 2.3.50 (latest at the time of this comment). No matter the permissions on the `tty` node, you get `Permission denied`.

Comment: @dpk, I see the same issue (`screen` tty to Docker VM not working) in 2.3.0.4. There are alternative methods which work to access the Docker VM, and as an added bonus, they don't exhibit the garbled output from `screen`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63445657/why-i-am-getting-screen-is-terminating-error-in-macos/63595817#63595817