# Why I am getting Screen is terminating error in MacOS

Tags: macos, docker, devops

When trying to enter into Docker VM in mac, I am getting screen is terminating error whereby I cannot go into Docker Desktop. In Mac, Docker host is not the mac as it runs as a VM. Any solutions?

[image: r]

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 37):

## Workarounds

I think it's a bug since version 2.3.0.4 of Docker Desktop for Mac, as I have used `screen` successfully to access the Docker VM in the past on Mac without this issue. (edit: this issue appears to be still present at version 2.4.0.0)

There are some alternative methods to access the Docker VM. Here is one that worked for me:

### workaround method 1

run this command to enter shell of the Docker VM:

```
docker run -it --privileged --pid=host debian nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i sh
```

Then you can do what you need to do at the usual location for Docker volumes:

```
/ # ls -lah /var/lib/docker/volumes/
total 72
drwx------   10 root     root        4.0K Aug 27 11:34 .
drwx--x--x   15 root     root        4.0K Oct 31 00:51 ..
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root        4.0K Aug 26 10:44 14ce94e174839f1947efa6fcbf5ac1fb2ea3b0f0b3f25311fee333ee374576b6
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root        4.0K Aug 25 12:34 34eb2bd80931ff954e1da80c5383beb4def61129d4005432b77080531cd10a5a
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root        4.0K Aug 27 11:34 830de2ce31519c921b50c448964b54517ca4461d337b56a9fd6e5b354ace3247
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root        4.0K Aug 25 12:34 data-layer_mongo_data
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root        4.0K Aug 26 11:01 ebb440184703bfad17184bd5ff74b677b50d74b8f0fbdd116506a1fcacfb00cd
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root        4.0K Aug 27 11:27 hawakening-services_back-end_log
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root        4.0K Aug 27 11:27 hawakening-services_front-end_log
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root        4.0K Aug 27 11:27 hawakening-services_mongo_data
-rw-------    1 root     root       64.0K Oct 31 00:51 metadata.db
```

### workaround method 2

Here's another one that also worked for me.

Run this command to enter shell of the Docker VM:

```
docker run --rm -it --privileged --pid=host walkerlee/nsenter -t 1 -m -u -i -n sh
```

As before, here is where the Docker volumes' directories are:

```
/ # ls -lah /var/lib/docker/volumes/
total 72
drwx------   10 root     root        4.0K Aug 27 11:34 .
drwx--x--x   15 root     root        4.0K Oct 31 00:51 ..
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root        4.0K Aug 26 10:44 14ce94e174839f1947efa6fcbf5ac1fb2ea3b0f0b3f25311fee333ee374576b6
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root        4.0K Aug 25 12:34 34eb2bd80931ff954e1da80c5383beb4def61129d4005432b77080531cd10a5a
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root        4.0K Aug 27 11:34 830de2ce31519c921b50c448964b54517ca4461d337b56a9fd6e5b354ace3247
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root        4.0K Aug 25 12:34 data-layer_mongo_data
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root        4.0K Aug 26 11:01 ebb440184703bfad17184bd5ff74b677b50d74b8f0fbdd116506a1fcacfb00cd
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root        4.0K Aug 27 11:27 hawakening-services_back-end_log
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root        4.0K Aug 27 11:27 hawakening-services_front-end_log
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root        4.0K Aug 27 11:27 hawakening-services_mongo_data
-rw-------    1 root     root       64.0K Oct 31 00:51 metadata.db
```

Comment: here's the issue https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4822

Comment: I also have this issue with Docker Desktop 2.4.0.0.

Comment: I also have this issue with Docker Desktop 2.4.0.0(48506), my computer is mac.

Comment: I get notifications to my answer, are you both saying that the workaround methods above also do not work for you?

Comment: @DavidOngaro I just re-ran both of the workaround methods above and confirmed they both still work on 2.4.0.0 of Docker Desktop for Mac

Comment: @linkliumayuyu I've confirmed both workarounds still work on 2.4.0.0 (Mac)

Comment: I didn't say that the workarounds aren't working, I just confirmed that I still cannot connect via screen (or via other means) to the tty.

Comment: Ok, I realised later that you were confirming it as an ongoing bug and updated my answer with that info. Thanks 

Comment: @SteveGoossens thank you for the workarounds. They are both still working for v.4.8.1 (mac)

Comment: @SteveGoossens thank you a lot! You saved me a lot of time. I tried out the workaround 1 and it still works for the Docker Desktop v.4.5.0 on macOS :)